# How to load a video from youtube with his player in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, video, download

I'm trying to display a youtube video with his player in my flash application. I was hable to do it, but I feel like I'm not doing it correctly, mainly because I don't know how to stop the video or destroy it when I remove it.

I would like to know if there's an other way to do it that would be a "better" way to do it and that would give me more control over the video (mostly pause and destroy)

Here is the code I got so far:

```
        public function openVideoYoutube(url:String, width:int=640, height:int=390):void
        {
            //Load the video
            var loaderVideo:Loader = new Loader();
            loaderVideo.load(new URLRequest(url));

            //Get the stage
            var stage:Stage = _app._root.stage;

            //Will contain both the video and  a shape to hidden the background
            var conteneurVideo:MovieClip = new MovieClip;

            //Shape to hidden the background
            var cacheNoir:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            cacheNoir.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
            cacheNoir.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.width, stage.height);
            cacheNoir.graphics.endFill();
            cacheNoir.alpha = 0.7;

            //Place the video
            loaderVideo.x = (stage.stageWidth-width)/2;
            loaderVideo.y = (stage.stageHeight - height) / 2;

            //Add the shape and the video
            conteneurVideo.addChild(cacheNoir);
            conteneurVideo.addChild(loaderVideo);

            //Add on stage
            stage.addChild(conteneurVideo);

            //Change cursor
            cacheNoir.buttonMode = true;

            //Event that remove the video
            cacheNoir.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onQuitVideoYoutube);
        }

        private function onQuitVideoYoutube(pEvt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //Get the stage
            var stage:Stage = _app._root.stage;

            //Remove video
            stage.removeChildAt(stage.numChildren-1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

I created a class VideoYoutube thta takes care of everything:

```
package source.game 
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author ...
     */
    public class VideoYoutube extends MovieClip 
    {
        private var _player:Object;
        private var _loader:Loader;

        private var _cache:MovieClip;

        private var _largeur:uint;
        private var _hauteur:uint;

        public static const FERMER_VIDEO:String = "FERMER_VIDEO";

        public function VideoYoutube(url:String, stage:Stage, largeur:uint, hauteur:uint) 
        {
            //Stock les dimensions
            _largeur = largeur;
            _hauteur = hauteur;

            //Cache noir
            _cache = new MovieClip();
            _cache.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
            _cache.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.width, stage.height);
            _cache.graphics.endFill();
            _cache.alpha = 0.7;

            //Charge la vidéo
            _loader = new Loader();
            _loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
            _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);
        }

        private function onLoaderInit(pEvt:Event):void
        {
            //Retire l'écouteur
            _loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);

            //Positionne la video
            _loader.x = (stage.stageWidth-_largeur)/2;
            _loader.y = (stage.stageHeight - _hauteur)/2;

            //Ajoute le cache et de la vidéo
            addChild(_cache);
            addChild(_loader);

            //Change le curseur lorsque que le cache est survolé
            _cache.buttonMode = true;

            //Stock le player
            _player=_loader.content

            //Lorsque le player est prêt
            _player.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);

            //Évènement pour retirer la vidéo
            _cache.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onQuitVideo);
        }

        private function onPlayerReady(pEvt:Event):void
        {   
            //Retire l'écouteur
            _player.removeEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);

            //Change la grosseur de la vidéo
            _player.setSize(_largeur, _hauteur);

            //Joue la vidéo
            _player.playVideo();
        }

        private function onQuitVideo(pEvt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //Indique que la vidéo doit être retiré
            dispatchEvent(new Event(VideoYoutube.FERMER_VIDEO));
        }

        public function kill():void
        {
            //Retire les écouteurs
            _player.removeEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
            _cache.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onQuitVideo);

            //Détruit la vidéo
            _player.destroy();

            //Détruit le player
            _player = null;

            //Détruit le loader
            _loader = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I got must of the code from here:
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3youtube/